# Python - How to compare CSV with duplicate Names and Increment values

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to take the First Column (Name) and the fourth column (is active) from a CSV file and do the following:

- Create a single entry for the Company Name
- If 'is active' = yes then increment the value and output the final result.
- If 'is active' = NO, then increment that number and give me a 'is active', 'is not active' list with a value at the end.

Data1 and Data2 fields are other columns that I don't care about at this time.

```
csv = 
Name,Data1,Data2, Is Active:
Company 1,Data1,Data2,Yes
Company 1,Data1,Data2,Yes
Company 1,Data1,Data2,Yes
Company 2,Data1,Data2,Yes
Company 2,Data1,Data2,No
Company 2,Data1,Data2,Yes
Company 2,Data1,Data2,Yes
Company 3,Data1,Data2,No
Company 3,Data1,Data2,No
```

Ideal result would be in the format of:

```
Company name, Yes-count, no-count
```

I've started with csvreader to read the columns and I can put them into lists, but i'm unsure how to compare and consolidate names and counts after that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One way to do, Use this:**

```
with open("your_csv_file", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    _ = next(reader) # skip header

    consolidated = {}
    for line in reader:
        company_name = line[0]
        is_active = line[3]

        if company_name not in consolidated:
            consolidated[company_name] = { "yes_count": 0, "no_count": 0}

        if is_active == "Yes":
            consolidated[company_name]["yes_count"] += 1
        else:
            consolidated[company_name]["no_count"]  += 1
```

**Sample Output:**

```
 >>> print(consolidated)

{
'Company 1': {'yes_count': 3, 'no_count': 0}, 
'Company 2': {'yes_count': 3, 'no_count': 1}, 
'Company 3': {'yes_count': 0, 'no_count': 2}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is EXACTLY what i was looking for. Kudos to you and now I also understand what I was doing wrong. Thank you kind sir

Comment: @NOC_NOC if this answered your question you may accept it.